# Php/Java Integration

Tags: java, php

Have you experience of integration of php and Java? I've written a class in Java "Hello". Now I want to call its method from php when I create an instance of this class from php with

```
$obj = new Java(Hello);
```

Then it gives me fatal error. I've tried many times to setup php ini variables etc but I couldn't find anything. Please advice me how can I set it up.

Thanks in advance

---

<sup>**Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/book.java.php**</sup>

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 12):

Have a look at:

[PHP-Java Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/)

> The PHP/Java Bridge is an
>   implementation of a streaming,
>   XML-based network protocol, which can
>   be used to connect a native script
>   engine, for example PHP, Scheme or
>   Python, with a Java virtual machine.
>   It is up to 50 times faster than local
>   RPC via SOAP, requires less resources
>   on the web-server side. It is faster 
>   and more reliable than direct
>   communication via the Java Native
>   Interface, and it requires no
>   additional components to invoke Java
>   procedures from PHP or PHP procedures
>   from Java.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be you are just missing the quotes around the Java Class? Also [make sure you actually do have a Java VM on the machine](http://de.php.net/manual/en/java.requirements.php) you are trying to run the code on and make sure you have properly [set up the config options](http://de.php.net/manual/en/java.configuration.php). Also, [the Java extension is a PECL extension and has to be installed.](http://de.php.net/manual/en/java.installation.php) It is not part of the native distribution. Furthermore, the extension is considered unmaintained and dead, so you might want to have a look at the [JavaBridge suggested elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319161/php-java-integration/3319178#3319178). [Zend Server also brings a JavaBridge.](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article: http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Using-PHP-with-Java/

They say it's possible (and how to do it).  I've never done it, so I can't vouch for it...

Comment: I've read this article. I think only problem is to setup java.home variable in php.ini. When i set it into php.ini and restart apache then I try to get the value of this variable but it returns null. I am using XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the best way to interact between Java and PHP is through a WebService layer. NuSoap for PHP is very good, and you can consume the webservice in Java to create a stub that will build the request/response object.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways few are:

- PHP Java Bridge
- Java Integration in PHP
- Using web services to pass data in between like SOAP
- Using simple HTTP data passage between Java and PHP see ([facejar uses the same technique](http://www.facejar.com/section/tv/index.php))
- Client site script (AJAX)

If you are after security, use option 1 otherwise I prefer using option 4 which is a bit faster when it comes to performance.