# Accessing to Java app from PHP

Tags: java, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Php/Java Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319161/php-java-integration)

I have a java app. It has some function. How can I call It's function in PHP?
I need step by step tutorial about it.
I need solution except Java/PHP Bridge and Thrift.

Comment: For Java and php communication you need web services.

Comment: did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045845/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-from-php ?

Comment: @Gordon: sorry - copy/paste too quickly. Thanks for pointing out the right link

Answer (score 0):

These are your options:

1. PHP/Java bridge allows you to pull in java classes into PHP code. Works relatively well, but has a bit of a learning curve.
2. Calling the java app through exec or system. Each system remains independent, but you can only transfer the output into PHP.
3. Use Quercus to run your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

You may use sockets to communicate between two different applications (regardless of technologies)

**PHP** take a look at some [examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php) from the PHP Manual

**JAVA** Use a [`ServerSocket`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) for incoming connections.