# Is there a way to import a java maven file into php

Tags: java, php, laravel, maven, import

i'm working on a project that requires me to import an existed java `maven` folder as a library/anything i could call and use it in `Laravel`. I wonder if there is any way to do it?

Comment: Broadly speaking, no, you can't include Java libraries in PHP directly, you need some sort of interface between the two

Comment: Can you tell me some of them please, those with documents would be the perfect ones. Thank you

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319161/php-java-integration